# Trying to acomplish a Loop determined by user input using "while (COM != "Y" || "N" )"

Tags: c++, oop, while-loop, char, boolean

So the problem I am having is in my Class `IOutro`, and in it's function `commandInput()`, my intention was to create a simple command based loop, asking if the user would like to use the program again or close it.

My goal with this program was to use classes only to store functions, the only thing I wanted in main was objects calling those functions. Just a first try with OOP.

So, The error have been getting when I attempt to run this.

```
 ||=== Build: Debug in Tutorials (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Tutorials\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Tutorials\main.cpp|57|error: could not convert 'COM.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"Y"))' from 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'bool'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I am not sure what I should be looking at, I am understanding it's a problem with my string I am using, it also gave me an error once, before some changes saying it could not identify `!=` Operator, I was thinking that `!=` means "Is Not Equal To" and `||` means "Or" (( Basically, if the left is NOT true, check the right value, if the LEFT value IS true, ignore the right value. ))

I am sure I am missing something simple, or maybe I am not looking up the right information. Can someone please enlighten me.

This is NOT for homework, I am not a student, I am self-teaching myself c++ and places like this are essentially my only place to find answers.

```
#include <iostream> // This is a PreProcessor Directive
#include <string> // Do I need this?

using namespace std; // This includes a library???

int A; // Global A
int B; // Global B
string COM = "Y"; // Global used to check if they want to keep going, not sure how to make this not global.

class Arith{ // Class for the calculator stuff.
    public: // Class is public.
        int sum(int A, int B){ // Sum, the actually calculation.
            int C = A + B; // Just math.
            return C; // Return value of C.
        }
        void calc(){ // Calc, not a calculation.
            cout << "Enter a number for A: "; // Ask for A.
            cin >> A; // Get A.
            cout << endl; // Make it look neat.
            cout << "Enter a number for B: "; // Ask for B.
            cin >> B; // Get B.
            cout << endl; // Make it look neat.
            cout << "The sum is: " << sum(A, B); // Print out the sum.
        }
};

class IOutro{ // Class for all informative prompts.
    public:
        void goodbye(){ // The goodbye class
            cout << "Thank you!" << endl; // Display a goodbye.
        }

        void welcome(){ // The welcome class.
            cout << "Welcome!" << endl; // Display a welcome.
        }

        void commandInput(){ // The FML check if they want to keep adding numbers loop of doom...
            cout << "Would you like to continue?" << endl; // Goal is to check if they want to keep going, Y or N.
            cout << "Please type 'Y' for Yes, and 'N' for No." << endl; // They are given options
            cin >> COM; // ???? Get COM

            while (COM != "Y" || "N" ){ // Trying to make it assure they type Y or N, and if they don't it keeps asking.
                cout << "Would you like to continue?" << endl; // Copied the text.
                cout << "Please type 'Y' for Yes, and 'N' for No." << endl; // For this loop.
                cin >> COM; // ???? Get COM, I am pretty sure it's suppose to be getline, but that doesn't work...
            }


        }
};

int main(){ // Indicates a Main Function which returns an Integer?

    IOutro IObject; // Declare the IOutro IObject Object?
    Arith ArithObject; // Same with Arith?

    while (COM = "Y"){ // If they chose Y, run loop
        IObject.welcome(); // Run IObject welcome
        ArithObject.calc(); // Run ArithObject calc
        ArithObject.sum(A,B); // Run ArithObject sum
        IObject.commandInput(); // Run IObject commandInput
    }
    IObject.goodbye(); // If COM != "Y" run IObject goodbye
    return 0; // Return the value 0 to main?
}
```

Comment: _`while (COM = "Y")`_ this is assignment , not comparison: `while (COM == "Y")`. Also you need a separate comparison expression for each term: `(COM != "Y" || COM != "N" )`

Comment: Perhaps taking case into account might be a good idea

Comment: Thank you, that cleared a HUGE portion of it up, not. It's giving me one last bit of trouble, and I am wondering I it's because of the Variable COM being a string...    `while (COM != "Y" || != "N" ` I double checked my `{}` and Semi Colons, but I can't find whats tripping this part up.. Is it because I declared something wrong?

Comment: the last issue would probably be because you are using `||` in `void commandInput()` change it to `&&` ( it worked for me ). ( also change string to char )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the problems in your code.

First, you don't need `COM` to be a string, it's more than enough to declare it as a char, like

```
char COM = 'Y';
```

Next, you should change the while loop condition in `commandInput()` from

```
while (COM != "Y" || "N" )
```

to

```
while (COM != 'Y' && COM != 'N' )  // if you don't want it to be case sensitive, then you will have to add small letters to the condition as well
```

Your condition is not right, you needed to check both like given above.

Now you might wonder why I changed the `||` to `&&`. This is because if it was `||`, if `COM` is not `'Y'` or `COM` is not `'N'`, the loop will continue. Now just think like this, if `COM` is `'Y'`, then it is not `'N'`, and if it is not `'N'`, then the condition in your while loop is satisfied, and hence, it just continues.

Now, lets look at the next problem. In your `main()`, you have

```
while (COM = "Y")
```

The `=` is the assignment operator, if you want to check for equality, then you need to use `==`. That is

```
while (COM == 'Y' )
```

So in short, a fixed version of your code would be ( I've removed your comments and added comments where I have made changes, there are changes in three lines )

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int A; 
int B;
char COM = 'Y';                    //  changed to char

class Arith{ 
    public: 
        int sum(int A, int B){ 
            int C = A + B; 
            return C; 
        }
        void calc(){ 
            cout << "Enter a number for A: "; 
            cin >> A; 
            cout << endl; 
            cout << "Enter a number for B: "; 
            cin >> B; 
            cout << endl; 
            cout << "The sum is: " << sum(A, B)<<endl; 
        }
};

class IOutro{ 
    public:
        void goodbye(){ 
            cout << "Thank you!" << endl; 
        }

        void welcome(){ 
            cout << "Welcome!" << endl; 
        }

        void commandInput(){ 
            cout << "\nWould you like to continue?" << endl; 
            cout << "Please type 'Y' for Yes, and 'N' for No." << endl;
            cin >> COM;

            while ( ( COM != 'Y' && COM != 'y' ) && ( COM != 'N' && COM != 'n' ) ) {     // made changes here
                cout << "\nWould you like to continue?" << endl; 
                cout << "Please type 'Y' for Yes, and 'N' for No." << endl; 
                cin >> COM; 
            }


        }
};

int main(){ 

    IOutro IObject; 
    Arith ArithObject; 

    while (COM == 'Y' || COM == 'y' ){         // made changes here 
        IObject.welcome(); 
        ArithObject.calc(); 
        ArithObject.sum(A,B); 
        IObject.commandInput(); 
    }
    IObject.goodbye(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Note that for this code, you don't need `#include<string>` and have also made the code insensitive to case ( that is `'Y'` or `'y'` and `'N'` or `'n'` )

This will get rid of that nasty error you were getting.

Well, hope that fixes the problems ( well, this solved it for me )

Comment: This is amazing! So much help! Not only does it fix my problem, now I have areas to look into later and read on. Thank you so much for the advice Arun A. S!